# Dired / Wdired: How to test whether a filename is relative / absolute

Tags: dired

I am creating a `dired-mode` buffer with:

```
(dired (directory-files-recursively default-directory ""))
```

This gives me absolute paths for each file, which is great.  I am still unsure how the `default-directory` in the resulting new `dired-mode` buffer is chosen.

Example, my dired- heading is:  `/Users/HOME/Desktop/0.r_d_w_1/Chase Checking/2015:`.  The file list, however, was recursively generated from `/Users/HOME/Desktop/0.r_d_w_1/` with many sub-directories -- i.e., not just "Chase Checking/2015".

The problem that I am trying to solve is that `wdired-get-filename` assumes that the filenames are relative.  When `wdired-get-filename` gets the **NEW** filename (i.e., after the `wdired-mode` buffer has been edited), it is *incorrect*.  What happens is that the absolute path of the **NEW** filename is concatenated to the end of the `default-directory`.  The problematic code looks like this:  `(concat (dired-current-directory) file)`, where FILE is the absolute path.

I would like to make `wdired-get-filename` play nice with absolute paths in addition to the default behavior which uses the `default-directory` and the modified relative-name for the **NEW** filename.

My initial thinking was to come up with a test to see if the the filename is absolute or relative, and then only concatenate if the latter.  However, I would certainly be amenable to a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely that wdired does not play well with Dired buffers that have an arbitrary set of files. I think you've discovered an example of that. Please consider filing a wdired bug report (`M-x report-emacs-bug`).

It's not too surprising. Few people know about or use the arbitrary-files feature of Dired. Wdired was written decades after Dired, by a single person I think, and probably that person was not aware of this Dired feature.

I don't really bother with wdired much, so I doubt if I've tried what you did. I do use Dired buffers with arbitrary files, though.

See `C-h f dired` for the buffer name - it's the non-directory part of the first element of the list you pass as the arg.  It's just a buffer name, not necessarily the name of a directory.  But if it corresponds to a directory then that directory becomes the `default-directory`.

In your case you passed `(directory-files-recursively default-directory "")` as the file list.  The first element of this is used for the buffer name and, if it names a directory or a file in a directory then that directory becomes the `default-directory`.  It was apparently `"/Users/HOME/Desktop/0.r_d_w_1/Chase Checking/2015"`.  Since it is a directory it is used as `default-directory` for the buffer.

---

If you use [Dired+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredPlus) then there are several ways you can take advantage of this feature. But as you've discovered, some tweaking of wdired is probably in order, to get reasonable behavior.

---

Wrt your subquestion about testing whether a file name is absolute or relative: see function `file-name-absolute-p`. ;-)

Comment: Thank you for the write-up and also for `file-name-absolute-p`.  I was tentatively thinking of using `expand-file-name` or `true-filename` (which according to one of the threads incorporates `expand-file-name` and also follows symbolic links).  It looks like some additional tinkering of the code will be required, and I'll have to just advance one hurdle at a time.  I'll probably wait to submit a bug report until I get a basic version working, and I'll need to compare that to the master branch to see whether some of these fixes may already be implemented (although that is probably unlikely).