# Updating `dired-directory` after renaming a file

Tags: dired, list

**Q**:   I have a list of strings:  `'("apple" "pear" "peach" "nectarine" "watermelon")`.  How can I replace `"peach"` with `"plum"` and maintain the same order of fruits?   [CAVEAT:  The list may be very long and the nth position of the element to be replaced will not be known at the outset.]

**BACKBROUND**:

I am working on implementing `wdired` compatibility with a `dired-mode` listing of files created by calling:

```
(dired (directory-files-recursively "/path/to/directory" "" 'include-directories))
```

This creates a listing of *absolute* paths to files and directories.  After modifying the `wdired` buffer, and pressing the command to finalize/commit the edits, here is what happens:

1. The files get renamed correctly using a revised version of `wdired-get-filename`, thanks to the assistance of @Drew in a related thread:  [Dired / Wdired: How to test whether a filename is relative / absolute](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/41275/dired-wdired-how-to-test-whether-a-filename-is-relative-absolute) .  [The renaming of directories (if applicable) will be dealt with by me on another day.]
2. `dired-readin-insert` does not work correctly to populate the buffer anew because the variable `dired-directory` was not updated with the new absolute path of the files that got renamed.

   `/path/to/bin/gls: cannot access '/path/to/filename': No such file or directory`

There will undoubtedly be additional hurdles to implement this new `wdired` feature, so I understand this will be one baby step at a time.  To resolve this particular question, I am looking for something a little fancier than `delete` and `push/add-to-list`.  Specifically, I would like to programmatically replace the old filename with the new filename and maintain the same list order.

---

EDIT:  Here is a link to the bug-report seeking an enhancement of wdired and dired:  http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=31601

Comment: You might want to retitle or rephrase your question, based on your answer. The answer is purely about replacing an element of a list of strings. It doesn't refer to Dired or Wdired or `default-directory` at all.

Comment: @Drew -- thank you for taking a look at this thread.  I was looking for a couple of things with this question:  (1) a quick solution to get me over over the hurdle, which the answer by @Andreas Röhler does well; and, (2) verification that `dired-mode` does not presently have the ability to update the `dired-directory` variable when a user renames a file in a buffer containing a recursive list of files in various subdirectories.  I tried to rename a file in a `dired-mode` buffer also in Emacs 26 using the recursive listing of files as indicated in the question, and the variable is not updated.

Comment: @Drew -- just a follow-up to let you know that adding `(when (and (listp dired-directory) (member file dired-directory)) (setq dired-directory (ar-replace--in-list file newname dired-directory)))` to `dired-rename-file` fixes the issue desribed in #2 of the question above.  I would imagine that this will need to be added to other aspects of `dired` such as deleting a file; and, there may be an issue with speed/performance.  Perhaps a hash-table system would be better suited to this type of job.  I'll submit an enhancement request to the Emacs team.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```el
(setq mylist '("apple" "pear" "peach" "nectarine" "watermelon"))

(defun ar-replace--in-list (elem replacement list)
  "Expects a LIST of strings.
ELEM: element to replace by arg REPLACEMENT"
  (let (newlist)
    (dolist (ele list)
      (push (if (string= ele elem) replacement ele) newlist))
    (nreverse newlist)))
```

So let's replace `pear` by `cherry`:

```
(ar-replace--in-list "pear" "cherry" mylist)
```

==>

```
("apple" "cherry" "peach" "nectarine" "watermelon")
```

Lists may contain other kind of elements than strings:

```el
(defun ar-replace--in-list (pred elem replacement list)
  "Expects a LIST whose type must fit to arg PRED.
PRED: a function to select ELEM
ELEM: element to replace by arg REPLACEMENT"
  (let (newlist)
    (dolist (ele list)
      (push (if (funcall pred ele elem) replacement ele) newlist))
    (nreverse newlist)))
```

Call for this example:

```
(ar-replace--in-list 'string= "pear" "cherry" mylist)
```